# Json Script assertion

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

would you please have look at my issue and see if you can help me? 
this is the Json response which includes the delays added on a task. I want to create a script assertion in SoapUI to check whether "taskid" in response is equal TaskId value in the testcase property or not?

```
[{
   "delayid": 7,
   "delaytypeid": 1,
   "autogrowminutes": 0,
   "seconds": 1800,
   "versionautoid": 10001308,
   "deleted": false,
   "taskid": 1163,
   "isprestartdelay": false,
   "starttime": "2018-02-06 09:30:00"
}]
```

my script assertion:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
def slurper = new JsonSlurper();
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent;
def parsedJsonResponse = slurper.parseText(response);
def tcTaskId =messageExchange.modelItem.testCase.getPropertyValue("taskId"); 
assert !(parsedJsonResponse.isEmpty())
assert parsedJsonResponse.taskid==tcTaskId
```

I got this error :

> assert parsedJsonResponse.taskid==tcTaskId | | | | | [1163]| 1163 | false [[autogrowminutes:0, delayid:7, delaytypeid:1, deleted:false, isprestartdelay:false, seconds:1800, starttime:2018-02-06 09:30:00, taskid:1163, versionautoid:10001308]]

it compares the [1163] with 1163 so result is false, how can I convert them to the same type?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you get an array `[1163]` instead of the number `1163` is because you are parsing JSON array (note the `[...]` in the response), and then you are fetching the field `taskid` from *all* of the elements of the JSON array, If you try with the following input:

```
[{
   "delayid": 7,
   "delaytypeid": 1,
   "autogrowminutes": 0,
   "seconds": 1800,
   "versionautoid": 10001308,
   "deleted": false,
   "taskid": 1163,
   "isprestartdelay": false,
   "starttime": "2018-02-06 09:30:00"
},
{
   "delayid": 7,
   "delaytypeid": 1,
   "autogrowminutes": 0,
   "seconds": 1800,
   "versionautoid": 10001308,
   "deleted": false,
   "taskid": 1164,
   "isprestartdelay": false,
   "starttime": "2018-02-06 09:30:00"
}]
```

You will see that `parsedJsonResponse.taskid` is `[1163, 1164]`

Since you check if the response is not empty, you can either do

`parsedJsonResponse[0].taskid==1163`

or

`parsedJsonResponse.taskid[0]==1163`

Both will work, however I suggest preparing for multiple elements in the response and do:

`parsedJsonResponse.taskid.contains(1163)`

Comment: Hi @GergelyToth , thanks for your help : yes exactly, so what I did,I thought what if I add more than one delay on this task? so I wrote this script :                                    
  `   for( i=0; i<parsedJsonResponse.size;i++)`
   ` {  `                                                                                                       
      `assert parsedJsonResponse[i].taskid == tcTaskId.toInteger(), "Delay` `not` 
        `added!";`
               `break;`
     `}`